# how to develop a share button to share a link?

Tags: android, share, mime

for example i want to share this link:

```
http://www.orientaldaily.com.my/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=6780:&Itemid=198
```

Here is the code

```
private void shareIt() {
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
    String shareBody = "Here is the share content body";
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
            "Subject Here");
    sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
}
```

So,

1) how to make it to share a link to facebook?

2) how to edit the share list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you hand the text off to the system with `createChooser()` its out of your hands.

1. It is upto user's choice, by which mean (*app/source*) they choose to share.
2. You cannot change the list of sharing application. (It is managed by system)

Comment: halo @Adil Soomro, can guide me? where should i put

    createChooser()

Comment: I didn't get you. where should you put chooser it is upto you, where do you want to share data..

Comment: for example like this?

`sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.orientaldaily.com.my/index.php?option=com_k2&view=item&id=6780:&Itemid=198");`

is this correct?

Comment: yea of course. It is a valid string and will be posted there.

Comment: i just get it successfully. Thanks